# Combobox items not showing when Windows DPI changed

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, ccombobox

I have a `CComboBox` based Custom ComboBox with `CBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE`. The items in Comboxbox are shown when the DPI is 96. But when DPI is greater 96 then items are not shown. I could not figure out what could be the issue. When I change `CBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE` to `CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` then everything is working fine.

[image]

When Scale & Layout value is 100% everything works fine. But if the scale percent is more than 100 then the items are not shown.

when scale percent = 100

[image: scale percent = 100]

when scale percent greater than 100
[image: scale percent = 125]

My code snippet for `DrawItem` & `MeasureItem`.

```
void CMyComboBox::MeasureItem(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpMeasureItemStruct)
{
   if (lpMeasureItemStruct->itemID != -1)
   {
     lpMeasureItemStruct->itemHeight = 16; 
   }
}

void CMyComboBox::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
   ASSERT(lpDrawItemStruct->CtlType == ODT_COMBOBOX);
   LPCTSTR lpszText = (LPCTSTR)lpDrawItemStruct->itemData;
   ASSERT(lpszText != NULL);
   CDC dc;

   dc.Attach(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);

   // Save these value to restore them when done drawing.
   COLORREF crOldTextColor = dc.GetTextColor();
   COLORREF crOldBkColor = dc.GetBkColor();

   // If this item is selected, set the background color
   // and the text color to appropriate values. Erase
   // the rect by filling it with the background color.
   if ((lpDrawItemStruct->itemAction & ODA_SELECT) &&
       (lpDrawItemStruct->itemState & ODS_SELECTED))
   {
      dc.SetTextColor(::GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT));
      dc.SetBkColor(::GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT));
      dc.FillSolidRect(&lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem, ::GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT));
   }
   else
   {
      dc.FillSolidRect(&lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem, crOldBkColor);
   }

   // Draw the text.
   dc.DrawText(
       lpszText,
       (int)_tcslen(lpszText),
       &lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem,
       DT_CENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER);

   // Reset the background color and the text color back to their
   // original values.
   dc.SetTextColor(crOldTextColor);
   dc.SetBkColor(crOldBkColor);

   dc.Detach();
}
```

Comment: It's hard to help with virtually no information. You need to show a picture instead of a description. And you need to show at least some relevant parts of your code. Yes, writing a good question takes some time. Good questions get good answers, bad questions get downvoted and closed. Read this: [ask]

Comment: Are you responding properly to the [`WM_MEASUREITEM` message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-measureitem)?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for suggesting. I have updated the question. Please check

Comment: @MarkRansom Please see MeasureItem() snippet code above. Is it correct?

Comment: Why are your functions `void`?  I'm pretty sure message functions have to return a code to indicate success.

Comment: @MarkRansom Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class?view=msvc-170#measureitem

Comment: Why are you blindly setting a hard coded value of 16 in `MeasureItem`? Surely the whole point is that you calculate the height that you actually need. And since you are factoring for DPI changes then you need to take that on board too. Most likely the issue is that you hardcoded it to 16 which is fine for 100%.  But when you make it larger your item height needs to be larger.